# How would you transform this into an WCF service that streams back images to an iframe?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, iframe

i'm currently working on a project where i have a bunch of tiff images on a file server that can only be accessed locally, all images are tiff which is giving me a hard time 'cause the images are to be displayed on a web browser, problem is, i have find myself having troubles solving this problem for good, here is what i have been doing:

**The problem:**

The people that want this update on the site had used a aspx page that received a request param to search for the tiff image, convert it to a png and "stream" the file to the client by using `Response.OutputStream.Write`, now, this process of converting the file and "streaming" it, is taking somewhere between 500ms to a full minute (and this are files that are 100kb at the most).

In the past, they used something called "alternatiff" which seems to be faster as it does not need the files to be converted before hand. problem is, this method requires to either use an iframe or an object.

**What i did**

Since i wanted everything to be more maintainable i decided to do some modifications to the way the page worked and use web services (asmx) + jquery ajax, now, as i researched on how to use the alternatiff it seemed like the only way to make this work was to transform the files to base64 string and embed them on the iframe src, as showed below:

```
var url = "/Web_Service/WS_Expedientes.asmx/getImagen";
        var type = "POST";
        var params = { 'ruta': $(this).attr('id') };//the id of the image that is being requested

        ajaxCalls(type, url, params).done(function (result) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            var str = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++)
                str += String.fromCharCode(result.d[i]);
            var img= btoa(str)

           //alert(JSON.stringify(img));
           //var img = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(result, result)).replace(/.{1,76}/g, '$&\n');

           //$("#visor-expedientes .wrapper").html("<object width=200 height=200 classid='CLSID:106E49CF-797A-11D2-81A2-00E02C015623'> <param name='src' value='tiffdocument.tif'> <param name='negative' value='yes'> <embed width=200 height=200 src='data:image/tiff;base64," + img + "' type='image/tiff'> </object>");

           //$("#visor-expedientes .wrapper").html("<iframe id='visor' src='data:image/tiff;base64," + img + "' />");

            $("#visor-expedientes").html("<embed id='visor' name='plugin' src='data:image/tiff;base64," + img + "' type='image/tiff'></embed>");
            //$('#visor-expedientes iframe').attr('src', 'data:image/tiff;base64,' + result);


        }).fail(function (error) {
            alert("error " + error.d);
        });
```

The above method only worked on firefox tho, as apparently there is a limitation as to how big the strings can be (apparently 32kb for ie and chrome, firefox seems to have this limitation as well but it seems like it allows for bigger sized strings). so currently the tiff viewer is only working on firefox, i really dont want to resort to use a aspx page that "streams" the file i would like to keep using web services for this, but ¿ how would you make it so that the iframe would consume the web service ? ¿how can i pass parameter to the web service from the iframe (a.k.a. the id of the image i need to display). I have tried simply putting the web service url onto the src field of the iframe, but that would not work either.

Thanks in advance.

---

PS:And this may be completely unrelated, BUT, Before somebody points out that asmx is quite "ancient" i must say, the thing is the client is using framework 2.0 and visual basic for this, even if i wanted to just switch everything to the newest of frameworks, i really cant 'cause that's part of what they want with this development, for them to be able to take the code and "fix it", and maintain it, should they need to, without putting any effort to learn something new (heck, even asmx seems like a completely ancien stuff to them, so babysteps i said in order to advance development methods, if only by a little.

## EDIT

Ok, i went ahead and started searching on the deepest of internet obscurity and came empty handed, so, i have decided to just give up and try and migrate over to wcf, the thing is, there is still no information regarding what the process would be for me to be able to do what i want to do, in other word, how would you translate this (which is what they are doing at the time):

ObtenerImagen.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ObtenerImagen.aspx.vb" Inherits="ObtenerImagen"  ContentType="image/tiff" %>
```

ObtenerImagen.aspx.vb

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim ls_rutaArchivo As String
        Dim key As String
        Dim lo_cryptUtil As New UtilSyc.Seguridad.Criptografia()

        If Request.Params("ruta") Is Nothing Then
            Throw New FormatException("La llave (ruta) debe ser una cadena válida")
        Else
            key = Request.Params("ruta")
        End If
        ls_rutaArchivo = lo_cryptUtil.Desencrit(key)
        '13464354
        Response.ContentType = "image/tiff"
        Response.Clear()
        Response.TransmitFile(ls_rutaArchivo)


    End Sub
```

And calling the page by adding an iframe with the src of the above page and the path of file to "stream back" to the iframe as a request parameter.

```
function visorImagenes(id) {
        $("#visor").html("<object width='75%' height='100%' classid='CLSID:106E49CF-797A-11D2-81A2-00E02C015623'> <param name='src' value='/Expedientes/ObtenerImagen.aspx?ruta=" + id + "'> <param name='negative' value='no'> <embed width='75%' height='100%' src='/Expedientes/ObtenerImagen.aspx?ruta=" + id + "' type='image/tiff'> </object>");
    }
```

¿ How would you go and transform the above aspx page into a WCF that can be consumed by the same iframe ?

Comment: Unwrap the tiff and wrap in pdf. For example if the image data is ccittg4 (b/w scan) it is quite simple to do

Comment: Can you elaborate on thsi process, im not aware of how to do this wrapping you speak of.

Answer (score 0):

Well, even tho i'm not entirely sure if doing this is the right way to do it, i solved my problem by doing the following:

create a WCF web service with a method like the one shown below:

```
<OperationContract> _
    <WebGet> _
    Sub ObtenerImagen()
        Try
            If IsLoggedin() Then
                Dim ls_rutaArchivo As String
                Dim key As String
                Dim lo_cryptUtil As New UtilSyc.Seguridad.Criptografia()
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/tiff"

                If HttpContext.Current.Request.Params("ruta") Is Nothing Then
                    Throw New FormatException("La llave (ruta) debe ser una cadena válida")
                Else
                    key = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params("ruta")
                End If
                ls_rutaArchivo = lo_cryptUtil.Desencrit(key)
                '13464354
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
                HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(ls_rutaArchivo)

            End If
        Catch e As Exception

            Throw New Exception("La session a expirado")

        End Try
    End Sub
```

And add the result to the page using the following line:

```
$("#visor").html("<object width='75%' height='100%' classid='CLSID:106E49CF-797A-11D2-81A2-00E02C015623'> <param name='src' value='/Web_Service/CPP_Service.svc/ObtenerImagen?ruta=" + id + "'> <param name='negative' value='no'> <embed width='75%' height='100%' src='/Web_Service/CPP_Service.svc/ObtenerImagen?ruta=" + id + "' type='image/tiff'> </object>");
```

Even to i'm still not entirely sure about if this is the correct way to do something like this (as stated above) it does work and solved my problem. Dont want to mark this as an answer yet tho, 'cause i would rather learn how to do this the right way before dismissing the topic completely.